# is it possible to set multiple base url in vue.config.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

My vue.config.js code is as below

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/prodserver1/' : ''
}
```

and it's working perfectly fine by hitting URL: abc.com/prodserver1/index.html (hostname + pathname)

But I have multiple production servers where I wanted to deploy the same application, let's say, I have one more production server named 'prodserver2'

How to pass multiple production server strings in base URL such that I can run app either on abc.com/prodserver1/index.html or abc.com/prodserver2/index.html?

Maintaining multiple applications for each server is not feasible as every minor change needs to updated in each time to each app.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.  You can't supply a path to a file or resource which references multiple possible locations.  However using a relative path instead should work.

From the vue documentation [baseUrl](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) it first of all suggests to use [publicpath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) instead.  In the publicPath description :

> The value can also be set to an empty string ('') or a relative path
>   (./) so that all assets are linked using relative paths. This allows
>   the built bundle to be deployed under any public path, or used in a
>   file system based environment like a Cordova hybrid app.

I suggest you use the option of a relative path, so you can then serve your app from any path.